# how to get files list of public or shared folder from either dropbox or google drive without authentication?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, dropbox

I want to get list of files which were either public folder or shared folder, is there any API without oauth for android application.

Answer (score 0):

You can query for the files shared with the authenticated user:

```
service.files().list().setQ("sharedWithMe").execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possible to access the API without authentication. According to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/about-auth) all requests to the Drive API must be authenticated.

Of course, the files themselves can be accessed without authentication. For example, a URL like this points to the publicly accessible files:

```
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=<some folder id>
```

However, the API itself appears to only support authenticated calls.

Comment: thanks a lot for ur answer, i get my data but actually i want data in JSON or xml format, Is there any idea? thanks